# How to prevent element with a big <ul> from overflowing body in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I had some serious trouble trying to phrase the issue i'm having, and i'm sorry if it's still not good enough

So, I have 3 cards on my app, and the 2 lateral ones have lists (`<ul>`) that can get pretty big, I want the scrollbar to appear on the `<ul>` itself, and not in the "main window".

This is how I want it to look:

[image: How i want it to look]

This is what happens instead:

[image: What happens]

I was able to take the first screenshot by setting `max-height: 80vh` on my lists, but this is a really janky solution, and it only works for a really specific screen-size.

[Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/levyks/pen/xxddPew), just press "Add more items" a few times and the issue will appear

Here's the "main" css and the basic html structure, in case you don't want to check the codepen

```html
<div class="room-wrapper">
  <div><button class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add more items</button></div>
  <div class="room-content">

    <div class="left-card app-card">
      <div class="left-card-wrapper">
        <div>
          <h3>Left Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="my-list"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-card app-card"></div>

    <div class="right-card app-card">
      <div class="players-wrapper">
        <div>
          <h3>Right Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="my-list"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.room-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.room-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  /* This would "solve" it, but only for an really
  specific window size, this is what i used for
  the first screenshot
  
  max-height: 80vh;
  */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some minor changes and by usng `flex` properties. I have made the solution working.

Just add the below extra css and your layout will look perfect.

```
.my-list {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
}

.players-wrapper,
.left-card-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```js
$(".add-more-btn").click(() => {
  $(".list-group").append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">Item</li>");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.room-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.room-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.app-card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.main-card {
  flex-grow: 2 !important;
}

.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.add-more-btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

.my-list {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
}

.players-wrapper,
.left-card-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="room-wrapper">
  <div><button class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add more items</button></div>
  <div class="room-content">
    <div class="left-card app-card">
      <div class="left-card-wrapper ">
        <div>
          <h3>Left Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group text-left my-list">
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-card app-card">
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <div class="form-header">
          <h3>Form</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="form-main">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
              <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-card app-card">
      <div class="players-wrapper">
        <div>
          <h3>Right Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group text-left my-list">
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nitheesh, this is perfect, and without adding any specific vh or % height figure, exactly what i wanted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #dadada;
}

.room-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.room-content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.app-card {
    height: 85vh;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.main-card {
    flex-grow: 2!important;
}

.form-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.my-list {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.add-more-btn {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="room-wrapper">
        <div><button class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add more items</button></div>
        <div class="room-content">

            <div class="left-card app-card">
                <div>
                    <h3>Left Card</h3>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <ul class="my-list">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="main-card app-card"></div>

            <div class="right-card app-card">
                <div>
                    <h3>Right Card</h3>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <ul class="my-list">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is what you want! Check out it.
> You can also see it here : [On codepen](https://codepen.io/Azizdokht/pen/abWWqvE?editors=0100)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #dadada !important;
}


.room-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.room-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100% - 78px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.app-card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  height:98%;
}

.main-card {
  flex-grow: 2!important;

}
.form-main{
    height:calc(100% - 78px);
  overflow:auto;
}
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-list {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 78px);
}

.add-more-btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

.right-card>div,.left-card>div{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="room-wrapper">
  <div><button class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add more items</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
 
  <div class="room-content">
    <div class="left-card app-card">
      <div class="left-card-wrapper ">
        <div>
          <h3>Left Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group text-left my-list">
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-card app-card">
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <div class="form-header">
          <h3>Form</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="form-main">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
              <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-card app-card">
      <div class="players-wrapper">
        <div>
          <h3>Right Card</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group text-left my-list">
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
          <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>  
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.room-content {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.room-content > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.room-content > div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0rem;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 72vh;
}
.list-group-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-block: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eae9e9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Three List</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="room-wrapper">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add more items</button>
      </div>
      <div class="room-content">
        <div class="left-card app-card">
          <div>
            <h3>Left Card</h3>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <ul class="my-list">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main-card app-card"></div>

        <div class="right-card app-card">
          <div>
            <h3>Right Card</h3>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <ul class="my-list">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```